# Why would dlopen reuse the address of a previously loaded symbol?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I just debugged a strange issue where I have two libraries let's call it libA.so and libB.so

Application <s>dlopens libA.so</s>(EDIT: it isn't: it's linked by the -l option) which is a thin library which then loads libB.so which is the actual implementation.

The dlopen are called using the RTLD_NOW option, no other options are passed.

And both libraries use the same logger module where the logger's state is stored in a global variable, since both use the same logger and linked to them statically the global variable in both of them is of the same name.

When libB is loaded the two global variables are sitting at the same address and conflicting. So the dynamic linker reused the address of the variable to use the same variable in libB.

If it matters this variable is defined deep within a .cpp file, I'm not sure if linking between C and C++ is different.

Reading the [dlopen's documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) it says:

> **RTLD_GLOBAL**
>
> The symbols defined by this library will be made available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded libraries.
>
> **RTLD_LOCAL**
>
> This is the converse of RTLD_GLOBAL, and the default if neither flag is specified. Symbols defined in this library are not made available to resolve references in subsequently loaded libraries.

So RTLD_LOCAL is supposed to be the default, that is libA's symbols shouldn't be used when resolving libB's symbols. But it's still happening. Why?

As a workaround I added visibility("hidden") option to this global to avoid exporting. And raised a ticket to make all symbols hidden by default, so collisions like this shouldn't happen in the future, but I'm still wondering why this happens when it shouldn't.

EDIT2:

Source example:

commonvar.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A inited. Address: " << this << "\n";
    }
    virtual ~A() {}
};

extern A object;

struct POD
{
    int x, y, z;
};

extern POD pod;
```

commonvar.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "commonvar.h"

A object;

POD pod = {1, 2, 3};
```

a.h:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" void foo();
```

a.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "commonvar.h"

using FnFoo = void (*)();

extern "C" void foo()
{
    std::cout << "A called.\n";
    std::cout << "A: Address of foo  is: " << &object << "\n";
    std::cout << "A: Address of pod  is: " << &pod << "\n";
    std::cout << "A: {" << pod.x << ", " << pod.y << ", " << pod.z << "}\n";

    pod.x = 42;
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "commonvar.h"

extern "C" void foo()
{
    std::cout << "B called.\n";
    std::cout << "B: Address of foo  is: " << &object << "\n";
    std::cout << "B: Address of pod  is: " << &pod << "\n";
    std::cout << "B: {" << pod.x << ", " << pod.y << ", " << pod.z << "}\n";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include "a.h"

using FnFoo = void (*)();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start of program.\n";
    foo();

    std::cout << "Loading B\n";
    void *b = dlopen("libb.so", RTLD_NOW);
    assert(b);
    FnFoo fnB;
    fnB = FnFoo(dlsym(b, "foo"));
    assert(fnB);

    fnB();
}
```

Build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ -fPIC -c commonvar.cpp
ar rcs common.a commonvar.o
g++ -fPIC -shared a.cpp common.a -o liba.so
g++ -fPIC -shared b.cpp common.a -o libb.so
g++ main.cpp liba.so -ldl -o main
```

Dynamic symbols of main:

```
                U __assert_fail
0000000000202010 B __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 U dlopen
                 U dlsym
0000000000202010 D _edata
0000000000202138 B _end
0000000000000bc4 T _fini
                 U foo
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000860 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U __libc_start_main
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
0000000000202020 B _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

Dynamic symbols of liba.so:

```
0000000000202064 B __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000202064 D _edata
0000000000202080 B _end
0000000000000e6c T _fini
0000000000000bba T foo
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000a30 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000202070 B object
0000000000202058 D pod
                 U _ZdlPvm
0000000000000dca W _ZN1AC1Ev
0000000000000dca W _ZN1AC2Ev
0000000000000e40 W _ZN1AD0Ev
0000000000000e22 W _ZN1AD1Ev
0000000000000e22 W _ZN1AD2Ev
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSolsEPKv
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
0000000000201dd0 V _ZTI1A
0000000000000ed5 V _ZTS1A
0000000000201db0 V _ZTV1A
                 U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

Dynamic symbols of libb.so:

```
$ nm -D libb.so
0000000000202064 B __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000202064 D _edata
0000000000202080 B _end
0000000000000e60 T _fini
0000000000000bba T foo
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000a30 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000202070 B object
0000000000202058 D pod
                 U _ZdlPvm
0000000000000dbe W _ZN1AC1Ev
0000000000000dbe W _ZN1AC2Ev
0000000000000e34 W _ZN1AD0Ev
0000000000000e16 W _ZN1AD1Ev
0000000000000e16 W _ZN1AD2Ev
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSolsEPKv
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
0000000000201dd0 V _ZTI1A
0000000000000ec9 V _ZTS1A
0000000000201db0 V _ZTV1A
                 U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

Output:

```
A inited. Address: 0x7efd6cf97070
Start of program.
A called.
A: Address of foo  is: 0x7efd6cf97070
A: Address of pod  is: 0x7efd6cf97058
A: {1, 2, 3}
Loading B
A inited. Address: 0x7efd6cf97070
B called.
B: Address of foo  is: 0x7efd6cf97070
B: Address of pod  is: 0x7efd6cf97058
B: {42, 2, 3}
```

As it can be seen the addresses of the variables collide but the function's address doesn't.

Moreover the C++ initialization are peculiar: aggregates the `pod` variable are initialized only once you can see that call to foo() modifies it, but when B is loaded it won't reinitialize it, but does call the constructor for the full object when libb.so is loaded.

Comment: Are you sure the main application is not using the same symbol?

Comment: @n.m. Yes it is... But the interesting thing is that problem started to appear when I wrapped the variable in `boost::synchronized_value` for thread safety. Before that it's used to be a plain struct. Could C++'s initialization stuff also plays a role here?

Comment: Well it looks like both your libraries are using stiff from the executable bit I don't know when exactly it happens and when it doesn't. I have an open question about it right now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174403/symbols-in-the-executable-are-not-preferred-to-symbols-in-the-library

Comment: Edited the question with source example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to answering this question is whether the main executable *exports* the same symbol in its dynamic symbol table. That is, what is the output from:

```
nm -D a.out | grep ' mangled_name_of_the_symbol'
```

If the output is empty, the two libraries should indeed use separate (their own) copies of the symbol. But if the output is *not* empty, then both libraries should *reuse* the symbol defined in the main binary (this happens because UNIX dynamic linking attempts to emulate what would have happened if everything was statically linked into the main binary -- UNIX support for shared libraries happened long after UNIX itself became popular, and in that context this design decision made sense).

Demonstration:

```
// main.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 12;

int main()
{
  printf("main: &foo = %p, foo = %d\n", &foo, foo);
  void *h = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
  assert (h != NULL);
  void (*fn)(void) = (void (*)()) dlsym(h, "fn");
  fn();

  return 0;
}
```

```
// foo.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 42;

void fn()
{
  printf("foo:  &foo = %p, foo = %d\n", &foo, foo);
  void *h = dlopen("./bar.so", RTLD_NOW);
  assert (h != NULL);

  void (*fn)(void) = (void (*)()) dlsym(h, "fn");
  fn();
}
```

```
// bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 24;

void fn()
{
  printf("bar:  &foo = %p, foo = %d\n", &foo, foo);
}
```

Build this with:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c && gcc -fPIC -shared -o bar.so bar.c &&
gcc main.c -ldl && ./a.out
```

Output:

```
main: &foo = 0x5618f1d61048, foo = 12
foo:  &foo = 0x7faad6955040, foo = 42
bar:  &foo = 0x7faad6950028, foo = 24
```

Now rebuild just the main binary with `-rdynamic` (which causes `foo` to be exported from it):  `gcc main.c -ldl -rdynamic`. The output changes to:

```
main: &foo = 0x55ced88f1048, foo = 12
foo:  &foo = 0x55ced88f1048, foo = 12
bar:  &foo = 0x55ced88f1048, foo = 12
```

P.S.
You can gain much insight into the behavior of dynamic linker by running with:

```
LD_DEBUG=symbols,bindings ./a.out
```

**Update:**

> It turns out I asked a wrong question ... Added source example.

If you look at `LD_DEBUG` output, you'll see:

```
    165089: symbol=object;  lookup in file=./main [0]
    165089: symbol=object;  lookup in file=./liba.so [0]
    165089: binding file ./liba.so [0] to ./liba.so [0]: normal symbol `object'
    165089: symbol=object;  lookup in file=./main [0]
    165089: symbol=object;  lookup in file=./liba.so [0]
    165089: binding file ./libb.so [0] to ./liba.so [0]: normal symbol `object'
```

What this means: `liba.so` is in the global search list (by virtue of having been directly linked to by `main`). This is approximately equivalent to having done `dlopen("./liba.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)`.

It should not be a surprise then that the symbols in it are available for subsequently loaded shared libraries to bind to, which is *exactly* what the dynamic loader does.

Comment: It turns out I asked a wrong question. libA.so is not dlopened (it's linked by -l) only libB.so is dlopened by libA. How would that affect linking?

Comment: Also the executable is not linked by -rdynamic but the symbol is still listed by nm -D.

Comment: If I don't define the symbol in the app but link the first lib with -l, then the symbol collision still occurs.

Comment: Added source example.

Comment: In the meantime I also found it out by reading the docs of dlopen more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this issue is using the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag of dlopen (however, it's Linux specific, not POSIX standard), which will make the loaded library try to resolve symbols against itself (and its own dependencies) before going through the ones in the global scope.

For this to work properly, the executable has to be built with `-fPIE`, otherwise some violated ODR assumptions made by libstdc++ will likely cause a segfault (alternatively, if `iostream` is replaced with `cstdio`, it works without `-fPIE`).

Comment: And there is also `dlmopen`.