# Symbols in the executable are not preferred to symbols in the library

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I have this simple example two-file program which I run on Linux (error handling skipped for clarity).

This is `main.c`

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int glo = 1;

void test(void)
{
    printf ("This is the main program\n");
    printf ("%p %d\n", (void*)&glo, glo);
}

int main(void)
{
    test();
    void* l = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW);
    void (*fun)(void) = dlsym(l, "fun");
    fun();
}
```

This is `lib.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int glo = 2;

void test(void)
{
    printf ("This is the shared library\n");
    printf ("%p %d\n", (void*)&glo, glo);
}

void fun(void)
{
    test();
}
```

I build them this way:

```
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
gcc -shared -fPIC -o lib.so lib.c
```

The result when I run them is this:

```
This is the main program
0x55af20d1e048 1
This is the shared library
0x7f6cb095d038 2
```

This means the library is not using symbols from the executable, but those defined in the library itself.

I don't think dynamic loading on Linux should be working this way.

The `dlopen` manual page says

> RTLD_DEEPBIND (since glibc 2.3.4)
>   Place the lookup scope of the symbols in this shared object ahead of the global scope.  This means that a self-contained object will use its own symbols in preference to global symbols with the same name contained in objects that have already been loaded.

The default is of course no `RTLD_DEEPBIND`, wich means the loaded shared object should prefer global symbols contained in objects that have already been loaded. Does this really happen? I've tried to debug the dynamic linking process:

```
LD_DEBUG=all ./main |& egrep glo\|test
 ....
 30374:     symbol=glo;  lookup in file=./main [0]
 30374:     symbol=glo;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
 30374:     symbol=glo;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
 30374:     symbol=glo;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 30374:     symbol=glo;  lookup in file=./lib.so [0]
 30374:     binding file ./lib.so [0] to ./lib.so [0]: normal symbol `glo'
 30374:     symbol=test;  lookup in file=./main [0]
 30374:     symbol=test;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
 30374:     symbol=test;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
 30374:     symbol=test;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 30374:     symbol=test;  lookup in file=./lib.so [0]
 30374:     binding file ./lib.so [0] to ./lib.so [0]: normal symbol `test'
```

It looks like the linker does look ip symbols in `main` before it goes to `lib.so`, but for some reason cannot find them.

What am I missing?

Comment: @nwellnhof I feel dumb. This should actually be `-rdynamic` gcc option. I somehow was sure it is the default.

Comment: @nwellnhof even though the manual page says the option causes all symbols to be added to the dynamic symbol table and not just the used ones. I'm pretty sure these symbols are used but they are not in fact added without `-rdynamic`.

Comment: Yes, the documentation of gcc's `-rdynamic` option seems a bit misleading, but the description of ld's `--export-dynamic` option is a lot clearer.

Comment: @nwellnhof  "dynamic symbol table will normally contain only those symbols which are referenced by some dynamic object mentioned in the link" yes this is much clearer